# How to submit multiple queries in hive concurrently

Tags: concurrency, hadoop, hive

I am trying to submit multiple Hive queries using CLI and I want the queries to run concurrently.  However, these queries are running sequentially.

Can somebody tell me how to invoke a number of Hive queries so that they do in fact run concurrently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not because of Hive, it has to do with your Hadoop configuration. By default, Hadoop uses a simple FIFO queue for job submission and execution. You can, however, configure a different policy so that multiple jobs can run at once.

Here's a nice blog post from Cloudera back in 2008 on the matter: [Job Scheduling in Hadoop](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2008/11/job-scheduling-in-hadoop/)

Pretty much any scheduler other than the default will support concurrent jobs, so take your pick!